# Why reducing an image size will rotate the image?

Tags: ios, image, parse-platform, rotation

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong in reducing image size or it is happening by saving in cloud.

I take an image with camera or camera roll and save it to parse cloud. When I retrieve this image and display it, it will be rotated 90 degree to left.

I checked the image on the cloud and it is saving rotated. But when I take picture with camera and before reducing size show it on `UIImageView`, it is not rotated.

Here is my code:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(userImage.image);

if (imageData.length > 10485760) {

    UIImage *compressedPNGImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    NSLog(@"Image is over sized");
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(480,320));

    //CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [compressedPNGImage drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
    UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(smallImage);

    PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithName:@"pic.png" data:imageData];
    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId] block:^(PFObject *user, NSError *error) {

        user[@"image"] = file;
        [user saveInBackground];

    }];
    saveImageBtn.hidden = true;


}
```

Comment: Unrelated (I think) but why do you needlessly create `compressedPNGImage` when you already have `userImage.image`?

Comment: @rmaddy good point. I just saw this piece of code on SO and use it.